# Deploy ember-cli-rails 5 app to Heroku - failed to compile ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, ember-cli-rails

I'm following [this thoughtbot ember-cli-rails guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/ember-cli-rails) but cannot get the heroku deploy working. I did have to change `bin/heroku_install` to remove the lines about bower, and other than that, this is following the setup guide.

I don't see any visible errors in the heroku output so I'm at a loss as to where to go next:

```
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to enigmatic-savannah-87434.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/enigmatic-savannah-87434.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/enigmatic-savannah-87434.git'
```

The entire deploy log is [here](https://gist.github.com/danman01/dac72fd26029a07971deb473edfbbcbe) if you have the time and will to have a look. Thanks in advance

My next idea is try the sample app, deploying that, and comparing the two projects to see what I may have added that isn't playing nice. Will report back how that goes...

Comment: did you try heroku logs? or heroku logs -t? you may see more info :)

Comment: Idk if lines 786 and 787 are trying to tell you something?

Comment: heroku log tells me: build started, next line: `Build failed -- check your build logs`

Comment: @KickButtowski thanks for the ideas -- I removed my local node_modules folder and tried again on a different internet connection, no luck...I don't see `fsevent` listed as a dependency directly, maybe a part of another package?

Comment: it is possible yet sorry I don't have enough knowledge about node.js ☹

Comment: do you have any email or wanna chat regarding to ruby ?

Comment: Sure, you can message me at rkirschner1377@gmail.com :ruby:

Comment: I had the same error! I could solve it by deleting the gemfile.lock running bundle install again and then adding it one more time to git and then pusing it... have u been able to solve it yet?